# Show and hide image(toggle image)

Tags: jquery, html, css

Suppose I have three images that are hiden by defaulted. If I click the icon, then the image is shown.
The demo is at [jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/zhshqzyc/tMmaa/)

Now the question is that the image is displayed at the bottom. What I want is to display it at the position of the corresponding text. At the same time, the text and small icon will be hiden.
Ex, clicking thumbnail of text 1, the image is shown on the top. Text 1 and the first magnifier thumbnail are hiden.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing a bit the markup:

```
<div class="slides">
    <div class="slide">
        <p>text 1<img src="http://www.moosemash.de/images/magnifier.jpg" height="27" width="30"></p>
        <img class="pic" src="http://www.moosemash.de/images/img81.jpg">        
    </div>
    <div class="slide">    
        <p>text 2<img src="http://www.moosemash.de/images/magnifier.jpg" height="27" width="30"></p>        
        <img class="pic" src="http://www.moosemash.de/images/img82.jpg">        
    </div>
    <div class="slide">    
        <p>text 3<img src="http://www.moosemash.de/images/magnifier.jpg" height="27" width="30"></p>        
        <img class="pic" src="http://www.moosemash.de/images/img83.jpg">        
    </div>    
</div>​
```

And the js:

```
$('.pic').hide();

$('.slide').on("click", function(event){

    $('.slide').each(function(){

        if(this == event.currentTarget){

            $('p', this).toggle();
            $('.pic', this).fadeToggle();               

        }else{

            $('p', this).show();
            $('.pic', this).hide();                           

        }

    });

})​
```

[Is this what you intended](http://jsfiddle.net/bk3jH/)?

Answer (score 3):

How about the following way ? Using less javascript.

**html**

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="slide">
        <p>text 1<img src="http://www.moosemash.de/images/magnifier.jpg" height="27" width="30"></p>
        <img class="slideImage" src="http://www.moosemash.de/images/img81.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <p>text 2<img src="http://www.moosemash.de/images/magnifier.jpg" height="27" width="30"></p>
        <img class="slideImage" src="http://www.moosemash.de/images/img82.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <p>text 3<img src="http://www.moosemash.de/images/magnifier.jpg" height="27" width="30"></p>
        <img class="slideImage" src="http://www.moosemash.de/images/img83.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
​
```

**js**

```
 $('.content p img').on("click", function(){
     $('.slide').removeClass('active');
     $(this).closest('.slide').addClass('active');
 })​;
```

**css**

```
.slideImage{
    display: none;
    position: "absolute",
    left: "0",
    top: "0",
}

.active .slideImage{
    display: block;
}

.active > *:not(.slideImage) {
    display: none;
}​
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tMmaa/2/)

Answer (score 1):

[Here is my solution](http://jsfiddle.net/ComboZhc/cwEhh/4/)

Html:

```
    <div class="content">
    <p>text 1<img src="http://www.moosemash.de/images/magnifier.jpg" height="27" width="30"></p>
    <img class="slideshow" src="http://www.moosemash.de/images/img81.jpg">
    <p>text 2<img src="http://www.moosemash.de/images/magnifier.jpg" height="27" width="30"></p>
    <img class="slideshow" src="http://www.moosemash.de/images/img82.jpg">
    <p>text 3<img src="http://www.moosemash.de/images/magnifier.jpg" height="27" width="30"></p>
    <img class="slideshow" src="http://www.moosemash.de/images/img83.jpg">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.content .slideshow').hide();
$('.content p img').on("click", function() {
    var index = $(".content p img").index(this);

    $("img.current").removeClass("current").hide();
    $("p.current").removeClass("current").show();

    var p = $(this).parent();
    var i = p.next();
    p.addClass("current").hide();
    i.addClass("current").show();
});
```